# MySQLProv / IBMDADB2 Provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, oledb

HI I got error while running a OLEDB connection open,I'm using windows 7 64-Bit Operating System,and Mircosoft Visual Studio 2012 Express, I used both IBMDB2 and MySQL database to connect using oledb but it not working, after I made many searches said

> **need to change the Debug mode from AnyCPU to x86, I tried that too but
>   still I m facing same error**

as either **IBMDADB2 / MySQLProv Provider is not registered on local machine.** Kindly find below my code which I used in the application

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

try
{
OleDbConnection mysqlcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = MySQLProv; DATA SOURCE=SAMPLE;UID=userid;PWD=password");
mysqlcon.open();


OleDbConnection db2con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2.1;Data Source=SAMPLE;User Id=Db2user;Password=db2password;Location=localhost;Connect Timeout=250");
db2con.open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in connection : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi Finally I found a solution, I was tried to connect a Database using  Add Connection Wizard and I found my correct Provider for both MySQL / IBMDB2 as follows

```
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1; DATA SOURCE=SAMPLE;UID=UID;PWD=PWD");

  OleDbConnection mysqlcon2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=ADsDSOObject; DATA SOURCE=SAMPLE;UID=UID;PWD=PWD");

                con.Open();
                mysqlcon2.Open();
```

Its worked well for me..!!